# Clicking a reach dropdown in testcafe

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests, dropdown, testcafe

I'm using testcafe in a React app and I'm having some trouble with making testcafe click a dropdown option from a Reach dropdown menu.

I can access the option with Selector after triggering a click on the button that activates the dropdown menu, but clicking the desired option doesn't seem to do anything at all.

However, the action is triggered if I reach the option via keys.

```
//This works
await t
    .click('[testid="menuButton"]')
    .pressKey('down')
    .pressKey('down')
    .pressKey('enter'); 

//This doesn't
  await t
    .click('[testid="menuButton"]')
    .click('[data-reach-menu-item]:nth-of-type(3)');
```

I made sure that the selection is made properly in the second case, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This test is successfully executed on my side:

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `fixture 1`
    .page `https://reacttraining.com/reach-ui/menu-button/`
test('test', async t => {
    await t
        .click('[data-reach-menu-button]')
        .click('[data-reach-menu-item]:nth-of-type(3)');
})
```

Perhaps there is more than one menu button on your page, so the '[data-reach-menu-item]:nth-of-type(3)' selector points to an invisible item. To check this, insert .debug() after .click('[testid="menuButton"]') in you code:

```
  await t
    .click('[testid="menuButton"]')
    .debug()
    .click('[data-reach-menu-item]:nth-of-type(3)');
```

After the test code stops at debug(), open the browser's development console, execute the `document.querySelectorAll('[data-reach-menu-item]:nth-of-type(3)')` command, and check if the first returned node matches the third element in the menu's dropdown.